# Delphi 6. How to set idTelnet.Connect timeout for early return on no connection

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-6

Calling idTelnet.Connect normally connects to the remote device instantaneously.
But,
if the remote device does not respond,
then the call to idTelnet.Connect does not return.
It waits for a response from the remote device.

This hangs the entire application.

How can I set a timeout so that idTelnet.Connect returns within nn ms
regardless of whether a connection has been established or not?

Comment: I recommend to run the code in a background thread.

Comment: Is there a ConnectTimeout property? If not, I would try the current Indy 10.6.2

Comment: In Indy 10, `TIdTCPClient` has a `ConnectTimeout` property.  In Indy 9, there is no `ConnectTimeout` property, but `Connect()` has an optional `ATimeout` parameter instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the remote device does not respond, then the call to idTelnet.Connect does not return.

Yes, it will - eventually.

> It waits for a response from the remote device.

Or until the OS finally gives up and fails the connection, reporting an error that Indy will then raise as an exception.

> This hangs the entire application.

That means you are calling `Connect()` in the context of the main UI thread, which you should not be doing in the first place.  If you must do that, at least place a `TIdAntiFreeze` component on your MainForm (and be prepared to handle any reentry consequences that may introduce).  Otherwise, move your socket code to a separate worker thread instead.

> How can I set a timeout so that idTelnet.Connect returns within nn ms regardless of whether a connection has been established or not?

You did not say which version of Indy you are using.  Delphi 6 is very old.  If you are using the version of Indy that shipped with it, then you are using Indy 8 or maybe 9.  `Connect()` has no timeout functionality at all in Indy 8.  In Indy 9, `Connect()` has an optional `ATimeout` parameter.  In Indy 10, the `ATimeout` parameter was replaced with a new `ConnectTimeout` property.

Comment: Thanks Remy forbsummarizing the issue.

Comment: Can Delphi 6 be upgraded to Indy 10?

Comment: [Yes, it can](http://ww2.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx).  In fact Indy 10 supports all the way back to Delphi 5.

Comment: I just started another question/topic asking for help to upgrade to Indy 10. Should I have continued here instead? I decided it would be cleaner to start a new one. I appologize if that was a bad decision.

Comment: @AndersJ: Posting a new question is correct, since you are asking a new question that is not related to this question about `Connect()` timeouts.