# Can Delphi 6 be upgraded to Indy 9 or 10?

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-6

The Indy version that shipped with Delphi 6 does not include the option to specify a timeout when opening a TCP connection. I have been informed in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42155019/) that Indy 9 and 10 can do this.

Is it possible to upgrade Delphi 6 to Indy 9 or 10?

I have so far been unable to locate a download of either, and equally unsuccessful in finding upgrade instructions.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indy 10 supports Delphi 5 and above. Comprehensive [download and installation instructions](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.en.aspx) are available on Indy's web site.

So, to answer your question, yes.  :)

There is also further information on installation and other migration issues in [Indy's KnowledgeBase](http://www.indyproject.org/KB/).

At time of writing, although the navigation links on the Knowledgebase page itself are broken, you can download the full knowledgebase document via the link on the Knowledgebase landing page (see above).  The link to the PDF document **is** working:

[image]

Comment: Actually I had already found the IndyProject web site, but when I read the warnings about possible defective packades I doubted I had found what I was looking for.

Comment: I noticed that my original post has been edited, changing "Telnet connection" to "TCP connection". My issue was/is that idTelnet.Connect does not allow a timeout to be used. Will my original issue be fixed after upgrading or has focus now mistakenly changed to "TCP connection" timeout instead?

Comment: The odd thing is, those "broken" links seem to be working fine.  Did you mean that as a result of impending maintenance they may *soon* become broken ?  O.o  Incidentally, I don't like posting links in answers, but the content in this case is too substantial to reproduce in the answer and there's no really useful subset of the information other than the "yes you can do it" part.  :(

Comment: Yes, the links seem to work, but the knowledgebase does not work. Most of the clickable links in it are dead.

Comment: @AndersJ I edited your question because `Connect()` is inherited from `TIdTCPClient` and the behavior you describe is not specific to Telnet alone.

Comment: @Deltics at the time I wrote that comment, the links were not working. It seems they have since been fixed.

Comment: @AndersJ - yep, which is why I suggested that you should download the  PDF document version of the Knowledgebase.  The (working) link to which was on the landing page of the Knowledgebase.  Remy chose to "helpfully" remove that suggestion and just leave the link to to the  landing page itself.  I've reinstated and further clarified that information.

Comment: Due to server / domain changes, the direct links are gone. [more information here](https://www.indyproject.org/2021/02/10/links-to-old-indy-website-pages-are-currently-broken/)